# Recovering a wordpress blog that got corrupted

Tags: phpmyadmin

recently i had my blog up and running, but i installed some new software by accident and messed it up.i have reinstalled my word press, and i was wondering is there a way i can recover my old post? I really would like to be able to add them to my new installed word press blog. I tried to use MyAdminPHP but didn't have any idea how to look for the post and fine them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't change the table prefix from `wp-config.php`, you can find your posts in the tables `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`.

Comment: No but they aren't there.

Comment: You mean the tables aren't there? or your posts aren't there?

Answer (score 0):

If your database has been corrupted or changed and you dont have a backup, and you cant get a backup from your host then you're possibly out of luck, but if all else fails you can often recover your posts from [archive.org](http://archive.org/index.php), but if your blog is VERY recent then this mightn't work. Anywy to try just type your url in there and look for the most recent snapshot, if they have any. Then (if they have a snapshot) it's a slightly painstaking job to copy and retrieve the posts, yet possible, I once recovered an entire website which had been completely lost, including images etc.

If archive.org doesnt have anything then there are others i think, including google. Type [`site:yourdomain.com`](https://www.google.ie/search?q=sdf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=923&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3ayourdomain.com&oq=site%3ayourdomain.com&gs_l=serp.3...8118.16258.0.16526.20.18.0.0.0.0.224.1673.13j4j1.18.0...0.0...1c.CEtBF66dLhg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=7157065338098fab&biw=1440&bih=737) into the search box and see what comes back. If anything does then click the double arrows to the right of the result so you get the preview and click the "Cached" link.